# C# serial port Data OUT overwritten

Tags: c#, animation, buffer, lcd

Im new to C# and but I have a problem where it seems that data output from the serial port is overwritten if i do not add in delays (message box in code).

I'm trying to send commands to a special LCD device via serial port, firstly a hard coded animation in a 2d Array, that didnt work, then i tried to read commands from a log-file (see code) and feed it out the serial port, didnt work either, now im simply coding my own splashscreen (1d array) and I'm having trouble with the data thats effectively sent out the port the my Device.

My code is mashed up because i've been trying a number of things. The data is output PERFECT (LCD displays the Image nicely) when delays are added in (the message box) but without them, it seems that some bytes are overwritten

Please ignore my commented code (i've been trying numerous ideas)

contents of 'splashscreen' , 1024 bytes

```
byte [] splashscreen = {
 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85, ...Deleted stuff....... , 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 
 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85, 
170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 
 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85, 
170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170
};
```

My Code Snippet

```css
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int frame;
                
                byte[] data = {0x20, 0x0c, 0x30, 0x12, 0x03, 0x32, 0x02, 0x30, 0x03, 0x32, 0x02, 0x30, 0x02, 0x31} ;
                byte[] data2 = new byte[10];
    
                progressbarProgress.Enabled = true;
                progressbarProgress.Visible = true;
                labelProgressTitle.Enabled = true;
                labelProgressTitle.Visible = true;
                labelProgress.Enabled = true;
                labelProgress.Visible = true;
                picturebox1.Enabled = true;
                picturebox1.Visible = true;
                
                serialPort1.Close();            // its openned elsewhere
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";  // duplication of params
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort1.Open();
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();      // just in case
                serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
    
                //MessageBox.Show("Interface Setop Complete");
                
                //assign Log file into file object
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Kabir\PROJECTS\INCOMING\DEV\SimpleSerial\log.log");
                file.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                
                //trying another method
                char[] buffer = new char[71451];
                int x = file.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 71451);
    
                // secondary commands - GFX fill mode
                data2[0] = 0x0e;
                data2[1] = 0x0;
                data2[2] = 0x0;
                data2[3] = 0x04;
                data2[4] = 0x00;
                data2[5] = 0x92;
    
                serialPort1.Write(data,0,14); // setup display
                //MessageBox.Show("Clear Screen ETC");
                while (serialPort1.BytesToWrite > 0) ;
                //serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
    
                serialPort1.Write(data2, 0, 5);//enable gfx fill mode
                //MessageBox.Show("GFX fill mode");
                while (serialPort1.BytesToWrite > 0) ;
                //serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
    
                serialPort1.Write(splashscreen, 0, 1024);
                while (serialPort1.BytesToWrite > 0) ;
                //MessageBox.Show("Fill Complete");
                //serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
    
    
                //for (counter = 0; counter < splashscreen.Length; counter++)
                //{
                //    //serialPort1.Write("" + (char)file.Read());
                //    //data2[5] = Convert.ToByte(buffer[counter]);
                //    //textboxRecieve.Text = Convert.ToString(data2[5]);
                //    serialPort1.Write(splashscreen, counter, 1);
    
                //    //progressbarProgress.Increment(1);
                //    //                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                //}
                serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
                file.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                file.DiscardBufferedData();
                file.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("DONE");
                //serialPort1.Write(" ");
                //serialPort1.Write(data,0,14);
                
                
                //for (frame=0; frame < 35; frame++)
                //{
                //    serialPort1.Write("" + (char)14+ (char)0+ (char)0+ (char)4+ (char)0 );
                //    for (counter = 0; counter < 1024; counter++)
                //    {
                //        serialPort1.Write(""+(char)animation1[frame,counter] );
                //        progressbarProgress.Increment(1);
                //    }
                //        //serialPort1.Write(animation1[)
                //}
                //serialPort1.Write("" + (char)14 + (char)0 + (char)0 + (char)0 + (char)16 );
    
                //////////data2[0] = 0x0e;
                //////////data2[1] = 0x0;
                //////////data2[2] = 0x0;
                //////////data2[3] = 0x0;
                //////////data2[4] = 16*10;
                //////////data2[5] = 0x92;
                //////////serialPort1.Write(data2, 0, 5); 
                //////////for (counter = 1; counter < data2[4] + 1 ; counter++ )
                //////////{
                //////////    serialPort1.Write(data2, 5, 1); 
                //////////}
                
                //serialPort1.Write("" + (char)14 + (char)0 + (char)0 + (char)4 + (char)0);
    
                //for (counter = 0; counter < 1024; counter++)
                //{
                //    serialPort1.Write("" + (char)splashscreen[counter]);
                //    //progressbarProgress.Increment(1);
                //}
    
                //for (counter = 0; counter < 1024; counter++)
                //{
                //    serialPort1.Write("" + (char)splashscreen[counter]);
                //    progressbarProgress.Increment(1);
                //}
    
                //counter = 0;
                //string line;
                //byte value;
                //char characters;
                //int filecharacter;
    
                //filecharacter = file.Read();
    
                //while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                //{
                //    for (counter = 1; counter < 100; counter++)
                //    {
                //        filecharacter = file.Peek();
                //        textboxRecieve.Text = textboxRecieve.Text + " " + Convert.ToString(file.Read()); //); // (file.Peek);
                //    }
    
                //    file.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                //    file.DiscardBufferedData();
    
                //    counter++;
                //}
    
                //file.Close();
    
                progressbarProgress.Enabled = false;
                progressbarProgress.Visible = false;
                progressbarProgress.Value = 0;
                labelProgressTitle.Enabled = false;
                labelProgressTitle.Visible = false;
                labelProgress.Enabled = false;
                labelProgress.Visible = false;
                picturebox1.Enabled = false;
                picturebox1.Visible = false;
                //serialPort1.Write( Convert.ToString());
                // start test routines
    
           //     if (flag1 == 1) // checks for function 1st entrance
           //    {
           //         textboxRecieve.Text = textboxRecieve.Text + serialPort1.ReadExisting();
           //         //DEL:AY a bit
           //         flag1= 0;
           //     }
           //serialPort1.Write("This is the stuff sent to the buffer"+DateTime.Now);
           
                
            } // end Button click event for TEST-BUTTON
```

Comment: Gawdawful mess.  You need to wean yourself off those discard calls.  Delete *all* of them and never use them again.

Comment: erm thanks? ...i did say ** "my code is mashed up because i've been trying a number of things" **